# How do I create virtual sessions with x11vnc?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, x11

How to create virtual sessions with x11vnc?

Comment: Can you describe virtual session in your case ?

Comment: i mean x11 session created by vnc server,not real user x11 session

Comment: you can use xrandr to create a virtual display first then use x11vnc to share it https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want x11vnc.  x11vnc is used for sharing existing X sessions through vnc.

You probably want vncserver.

A quick guide to starting up:

```
$ vncpasswd
Password:
Verify:
$ vncserver :1
```

Then launch vncviewer on the remote node, and connect to display 1.